# open chromium portable .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, chromium

I've written a .bat file to open chromium portable in to kiosk mode on the page I want like a full screen app. This works great. My problem is it doesn't work if it's in a folder with spaces in. I know I probably need to add quotes somehow but not sure how to do it using the `%cd%` command can anyone tell me how to make my .bat file work from any folder? The code is below:

```
@echo off
start %cd%\appdata\chromeportable.exe --kiosk %cd%\appdata\app.html
```

How can i edit it so that it will run from folders with spaces in the title!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite follow your question, but here are a few things to try

To change directory to a path with spaces use

```
cd "C:\folder\folder with spaces"
```

To start the batch file from a folder with spaces from another directory

```
"C:\folder\folder with spaces\openchromium.bat"
```

If this isn't what you are trying to do please improve your question.

**Update**

After posting your code I can see a possible issue. When you use `start` and the path in the first argument is quoted it will treat it as the title, to fix this you give it a blank title like this

```
start "" "%cd%\appdata\chromeportable.exe" "--kiosk %cd%\appdata\app.html"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: sorry i forgot to add my current code it should hopefully make sense now, i need to use quotes like you did but using the %cd% command because the directory it's in varies

Comment: You correctly suggested using quotes, then forgot to add quotes to 2nd and 3rd parameters in your last code.

Comment: The third parameter is likely just `--kiosk`, without the path following it, and so just the path needs to be quoted, but I guess the OP has sorted that out.